# Importing PDF to String in java

Tags: java, pdf, text, itext, extract

i need to extract text from a pdf file using java. I found iText but it doesn't work the way i wanted it to. Here's my code

```
package com.itextpdf.mavenproject1;


import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfButtonFormField;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.action.PdfAction;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfTextAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import com.itextpdf.test.annotations.WrapToTest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class zczytywanie {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


       PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("D:/pdf/pdf"));

       String page= PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDoc, 1);

       System.out.println(page);

    }
}
```

And it tells me that there is an error in the line where i try to use PDdfTextExtractor (PdfDocument can not be converted to pdfPage, although i found that pdfDoc has to be PdfReader)

It doesn't work with

PdfReader pdfDoc = new PdfReader("D:/pdf/pdf");

either.

Comment: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html It takes a PdfReader object. I would also vaguely assume that D:/pdf/pdf is not a PDF file as it does not have a PDF extension.

Comment: As i wrote, i tried with a pdfreader also, if i try to make pdfDoc a pdfReader it says "PdfReader can not be converted to pdfPage". The D:/pdf/pdf is a mistake, but it doesn't matter to the compiler i dont think, the error for this should come up when the program is already built and running.

Comment: Check your itext version, PdfTextExtractor takes a reader since 2.1.4

Comment: There are two `PdfTextExtractor` on your import, one from `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor` and other from `com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfTextExtractor`. Are you referencing the right one, how is your classpath?

Comment: Previous commenter is spot on. You are mixing iText 5 and iText 7 classes!

Comment: @Matt Did fn's and Amedee's hints solve the issue for you? Or do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can try PDFBox or Tikka. But here I am giving an example for PDFBox

Add the PDFBox jar dependency to your pom.xml.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Java class**

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

    public class TestPDF {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("/path_to_your_pdf_file"))) {
               document.getClass();
    
               if(!document.isEncrypted()){
                   PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
                   stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    
                   PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                   String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                   System.out.println("Text:" + pdfFileInText);
                   
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }
```